# How to validate the comma separated emailIds in mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-esb

I have string with common separated emailIDs like below

```
abc@mail.com,xyz@gmail.com
```

I tired to validate through validator component. It is validating only one email.

Can you please help me. How to handle this in mule

Answer (score 0):

Place the Mule validation inside for-each component and loop through the emails. See the below example code.

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8085" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="mule_validatorFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="--- The service has been triggered ---" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-payload value="rk@gmail.com,rk1@gmail.com,rk2@gmail.com" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <foreach collection="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.split(payload, ',')]" doc:name="For Each">
        <validation:is-email email="#[payload]" doc:name="Validation"/>
    </foreach>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Groovy or Java Transformer and do:

`return payload.split(",")`

Your payload will then be an array of strings, each being an email.

Edit: that is, assuming your payload is the String containing your emails. If not simply use the variable or get the proper string and use the `split()` function.